# Implement JS from HTML file into a reactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app that uses the neighbor-joining package to develop a newick string. I also have an HTML file with JS included that can visualize the newick string with tnt.tree. I can't figure out how to implement it directly into my react app though.

react code to generate newick string:

```
import { RapidNeighborJoining } from "neighbor-joining";
var D_Matrix = [
    [0.0000000, 0.4965986, 0.50340136, 0.51020408, 0.50675676, 0.50675676],
    [0.4965986, 0.0000000, 0.11643836, 0.13698630, 0.13698630, 0.13698630],
    [0.5034014, 0.1164384, 0.00000000, 0.04794521, 0.04794521, 0.04794521],
    [0.5102041, 0.1369863, 0.04794521, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000],
    [0.5067568, 0.1369863, 0.04794521, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000],
    [0.5067568, 0.1369863, 0.04794521, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000],
];

var taxa = [
    {name: "Fish", genotype: "HB"},
    {name: "Rabbit", genotype: "HB"},
    {name: "Cat", genotype: "HB"},
    {name: "Human", genotype: "HB"},
    {name: "Bear", genotype: "HB"},
    {name: "Shark", genotype: "HB"}
];

// Distance matrix and taxonomy data used to create newick string
var RNJ = new RapidNeighborJoining(D_Matrix, taxa);
RNJ.run();
var treeNewick = RNJ.getAsNewick();
```

HTML/JS to visualize resulting newick string:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tntvis.github.io/tnt.tree/build/tnt.tree.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://tntvis.github.io/tnt.tree/build/tnt.tree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    <script>
    var newick = "NEWICK STRING FROM REACT APP PASTED HERE";
    var tree = tnt.tree();
    tree
        .data(tnt.tree.parse_newick(newick))
        .node_display(tree.node_display()
            .size(4)
            .fill("#888888")
        )
        .label (tnt.tree.label.text()
            .fontsize(12)
            .height(24)
        )
        .layout(tnt.tree.layout.vertical()
            .width(650)
            .scale(false)
        );
    tree(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
    </script>
</body>
```

I tried putting it inside the render part of my App class like so but its just loads a blank page:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                HTML PASTED HERE
            </div>
        );
    }    
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The React code you have here does not show an attempt at using your visualization code. It's unclear what you're having difficulties with. You should show any errors or incorrect  behavior that resulted from what you have tried. As your question stands, you're asking for us to implement it for you. Please give it a real try, then post what you have tried and what didn't work.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is nothing inside the div `mydiv` first make sure to check that your tree function is working by inspecting its output

Comment: Here are links that should guide you on how to render VanillaJS components inside a React component https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/wrap-a-vanilla-javascript-package-for-use-in-react https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/August_2019/how-to-use-hooks-reactify-plain-javascript-library

Answer (score 0):

You should append the node to your React tree in componentDidMount:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.containerRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.containerRef.appendChild(tree);
}


render() {
    return <div ref={this.containerRef}/>
}
```